# Parse .htaccess credentials in Internet Explorer

Tags: selenium, webdriver, ie9

I am trying to access a `.htaccess` protected test url 
 and I get the following error  When i am trying to run the tests in IE

```
Failed to navigate to http://Username:Password@www.xxxxxx.com/svn/branches/xxxxxx/public_html. This usually means that a call to the COM method IWebBrowser2::Navigate2() failed. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

The credentials are correct and the tests run fine in FF and chrome

Comment: You may want to include information about what sort of tests you are running, what tool you are using to execute them, etc.

Comment: Is that a supported feature of IE ? I think that may not be supported on security grounds.

Comment: @SamWoods I am running selenium Tests with Junit

Comment: @BruceMcleod it seams you are right according to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489    thanks for pointing me to the right Direction

Comment: @BruceMcLeod it seems that your comment worth an answer I'd upvote.

Comment: @theo If my comment helped, please mark this as answered to get it off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [support.microsoft.com/kb/834489](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489) this feature is not supported in IE on security grounds.